Can't compile beginners tutorial for GTK on Ubuntu 22.04
This is my first stack post, so forgive me if the formatting etc's a bit off.
Im following the beginners GTK tutorial near the end of this page
Same issue mentioned here, except those users are on windows.
When I put mcs hello.cs -pkg:gtk-sharp-2.0 into the terminal, I get
Package gtk-sharp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk-sharp-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'gtk-sharp-2.0' found
error CS8027: Error running pkg-config. Check the above output.


I went on to try installing GTK 3 and 4 using:
sudo apt install libgtk-3-dev
sudo apt install libgtk-4-dev
sudo apt-get update
And tried the previous command with different versions, same output. Using dpkg -s libgtk-3-0 | grep 'Version' shows a version for GTK3, but says V 2 and 4 are not installed. 

Im finding more info about pkg-config, and where gtk-sharp should be.
Looking all over the internet and youtube, I noticed references to GTK, GTK+, GTK# etc, have I installed the wrong thing altogether?

Two points: 1. You do not need two versions at once. Just libgtk-4-dev is enough.

Package name as it is known to apt and pkg-config differ. To see how the library is known to pkg-config, do pkg-config --list-all | grep gtk It will print all gtk related packages.


gtk-dotnet-2.0                      Gtk.DotNet - .NET Extensions for Gtk
gtk-sharp-2.0                       Gtk - Gtk
gtk4                                GTK - GTK Graphical UI Library
gtk4-unix-print                     GTK - GTK Unix print support
gtk4-wayland                        GTK - GTK Graphical UI Library
gtk4-x11                            GTK - GTK Graphical UI Library
Strange, although not needed I thought we could have multiple versions installed? Ah well. I did find an anser, Ill add it in a sec.

After reading a lot more I realised GTK, GTK+ and GTK# seem have some different components. I needed to specifically install GTK#, which I did with:
sudo apt install gtk-sharp2

The test script now builds with MCS. Hopefully that’s everything setup and good to go.
